# How to find at which point is the port being being blocked

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, port

I have a remote server running listening on a particular port.

Occasionaly I get a scenario where suddenly a client cannot connect to the server on that port. It is a random issue where some other PC's can connect but 1 in 100 may be unable to connect.

The clients are using Windows PC where as the server is on Linux.

I have done the following to trace the error.

1. Run `netstat` on the client to find if that port is in use. Netstat does not find any process using that port.
2. Disabling `Windows Firewall` or any other firewalls. Again no luck here.
3. Running `portqry` on the client PC and it shows that the port is **FILTERED**

As I said this only occures on random clients if I run `portqry` at the same time on another client the port shows as **LISTENING** so it seems something is going wrong on the client side.

So for the only solution I have found is a complete **reintstall** of the OS on the client side.

How do I figure where exactly in the the line  from client to server is the port being blocked?

**EDIT**

I have tried the following things

- ping works ok
- tracert shows around 20 hops and ends succesfully.
- nmap shows port **filtered** but does a successful tracert.

Answer (score 0):

`portqry` only shows the same problem as the client software being unable to connect.

I'm guessing your clients are using NAT? With some clients connecting while others can't, this pretty much rules out remote problems (as they're likely to use the same public IP). However, if you're using an egress IP pool this could very well be the problem when different IP addresses don't fit remote server access restriction.

The remote server/firewall might also be limiting the number of connections from a single IP address.

You'll need to check your access firewall/router for any problems. Can the clients in question ping the remote server? Access other servers normally? What does a `tracert` show up? Is the firewall logging anything for these clients?

Possibly, a client reinstall just works because it takes a while and allows the problem to move elsewhere.

If you can reproduce the problem at one point I'd try Wireshark to find out who sends the port reset (and thus rejects the connection).

Comment: I haven't tried pinging yet only `portqry`. You see clients from different locations are connecting to the server so their IP may be diffirent. Some times many clients from the same location too. Is there a tool (some thing like `tracert` but with port included too) that will tell me exactly where the port is being blocked? Is it on the PC on somewhere down the line at the ISP or further

Comment: `tracert` shows up multiple hops just fine, it seems that the IP address can be reached but he port is being blocked somewhere

Comment: `traceroute` on Linux can also use UDP or TCP syns. If suddenly no _new_ clients can connect from a location you might want to try that - there are tools for Windows as well.

Comment: clients can connect from all locations. its just that at certain times a partcular time a client may be unable to connect due to unknown reasons, eg. if there are 10 client at 1 location, 9 would connect but 1 can't. So it seems to be something with the client or his connection to the server. It also happens sometimes that a client who could connect upto yesterday cannot connect today

Comment: Since `portqry` isn't connecting with the message `filtered` would'nt you think that its some port block issue down the line or on the client.